# Delete data from table with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Can you explain me where is the problem? Because I lost all my hope for this...
Insert and load work but delete not... When I remove if statement from delete, it says id is undefined index. But why it should be undefined when I define it in `var id = $(this).data("id3");` I think the problem will be somewhere in select.php with a button.
I have lack of experience with AJAX so I ask you for help with this problem.

Thank you for response. (sorry for the language)

Index.php

```
$('.btn_delete').on('click', function()
{
    var id = $(this).data("id3");

    if (confirm('Naozaj zmazat ?')) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {delete: 1, id: id},
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                fetch_data();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

delete.php

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    include("db.php");

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);    
    $sql = "DELETE FROM suciastka WHERE id_suciastka = '".$id."'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Deleted";
    }
}
```

And here is my select.php

```
include("db.php");

$output = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM suciastka";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$output .= "
        <div class='table-responsive'>
            <table class='table table-bordered'>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>NUMBER</th>
                    <th>PLACE</th>
                    <th>DESCR</th>
                    <th>ACTION</th>
                </tr>";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {   
        $output .= "
            <tr>
                <td>".$row['id_suciastka']."</td>
                <td>".$row['name_suciastka']."</td>
                <td>".$row['number_suciastka']."</td>
                <td>".$row['place_suciastka']."</td>
                <td>".$row['descr_suciastka']."</td>
                <td><button type='button' name='delete_btn' data-id3='".$row['id_suciastka']."' class='btn btn-danger btn_delete'>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>";
    }

}

$output .= "</table>
        </div>";

echo $output;
```

Comment: Did you console the `id`in js. What was the output

Comment: There is no error in console because when i click on button it will do nothing and i do not know why because i target that button in ajax .btn_delete

Comment: I meant to console the value of `id` before going to ajax. The value of => `var id = $(this).data("id3");` Check whether the correct value is assigned or not

Comment: why do you need to pass `delete` as a var if it's pointing to the delete script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your button is not in the DOM
You can try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function() {})
```

Comment: Yes you are right. This was the problem. I thought it was enough when it is targeted with `$('.btn_delete')`

Comment: my technique always is to use the `view page source` to check if the data is in the DOM. But why it isnt in the DOM. You are not using `PHP` for `view`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's debug this code step by step :

First of all, we should check the content of `$_POST` in your PHP code :
`die(var_dump($_POST));` at the top of delete.php.

Do you see your id?

If yes, then... Just be sure you typed the right index name :)
If no, we have to get closer to the browser :

Open your code inspector (Ctrl+Maj+I on chrome), get to the Network panel. When you fire your AJAX query, a new line will apper! Just click on it, you will find in the "Headers" section all data about request/Response, and at the bottom you'll find the data you sent!
[image: Network]

Do you see your id?
If yes, then there is code you didn't show us that do whatever something that erase your data or something ^^

If no, let's take a look in the javascript :
Still in the Inspector, open the "source" pannel and find  your index.php, and more precisely the code you sent us.
[image: Sources]
Just add a marker after your `var id = ...` by clicking on the line numbers.
Fire your ajax request again. You will be able to see your value of `id`.
Is the value correct? If yes... well boy, we have to keep digging together!

If no (it is "undefined" or "null"), then that's why the browser doesn't send it!
In this case, you have to check the value of `$row['id_suciastka']`, for exemple by using a `var_dump($row);` at the begining of your loop in index.php.

If nothing seems to work, then we have to get more informations on the problem!

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn_delete').on('click', function(){
var id = $(this).data("id3");

if (confirm('Naozaj zmazat ?')) 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'delete.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {delete:1, id:id},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            fetch_data();
        }
    });
}
});
```

Replace type with Method in ajax request.

Answer (score -1):

For start, you can `console.log` id before you send a post request, so try

```
$('.btn_delete').on('click', function(){
            var id = $(this).data("id3");
            console.log(id); // <-- log ID here  
            if (confirm('Naozaj zmazat ?')) 
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'delete.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {delete:1, id:id},
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        fetch_data();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

If you get something there, then hit F12 in Chrome or Firefox and in dev tools, go to network tab and inspect http request to your PHP and in "headers" tab check "Form data" section of request (body of http request). 
If you get ID and delete properties there, then your JS is correct and you should look for bug in PHP.

Best way to start on that would be to `var_dump` whole `$_POST` array. So:

```
var_dump($_POST);

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {

    include("db.php");

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);

    $sql = "DELETE FROM suciastka WHERE id_suciastka = '".$id."'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        echo "Deleted";
    }
}
```